# SIGBUS when trying to call recv on socket after server crash (Android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, signals, sigbus

I am currently doing some app stability testing and I am running in to an issue when calling the following method;

```
    vector<char> buffer( 256 ); 
    received = recv( fd, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL );
```

In this case `fd` is a TCP socket. When the above code is called and simultaneously the server side of the socket goes down in one way or another I get the following signal;

> SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)

It only seems to happen on Android 6.0.1 and I can't seem to 'ignore' the SIGBUS using

```
signal(SIGBUS, SIG_IGN)
```

Has anyone else run in to this problem and what would be the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke, I have found out the issue. It has NOTHING to do with the call to `recv`. The signal occurs when and `std::exception` is being throws on Android 6.0.1. Even though it blames the recv call. This seemed to be caused by the c++_shared STL version I am using. The solution was to switch to `gnustl_static` or `gnustl_shared`.